h:commandButton el action no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?
Os detallo, tengo un proyecto Web Service hecho en Java usando JSF, el problema es que el atributo action de la etiqueta <h:commandButton> no ejecuta la función authenticationBean.login.
Os muestro el codigo del login.jsp:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>

<%@page import="javax.faces.context.FacesContext"%>
<%@page import="com.project.web.security.AuthenticationBean"%>

<f:loadBundle basename="bundle.site.Messages" var="userMessage" />

<html>
<head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <link href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="fondoBody" onload="loadWindow();">

<script type="text/javaScript">

    function initForm(formInst) {
        if (document.forms.length > 0) {
            var frm = document.forms[formInst];
            frm.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
            frm.elements[0].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
            frm.elements[0].value = '';
            frm.elements[1].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
            frm.elements[1].value = '';
            frm.elements[0].focus();
        }
    }

    function putFocus(formInst, elementInst) {
        if (document.forms.length > 0) {
            document.forms[formInst].elements[elementInst].focus();
        }     
    }
 
    function loadWindow() {
         getWindowSize();
         
         if ((document.forms['newUser'].elements['newUser:showpw']).checked == null) {
             (document.forms['newUser'].elements['newUser:showpw']).checked = false;
         }
         showPassword();
    }
     
    function getWindowSize() {
        document.getElementById('newUser:windowWidth').value = screen.width;
    }
     
    function showPassword() {
         var showPwType = document.getElementById("passwordInput");
         
         var showPw = (document.forms['newUser'].elements['newUser:showpw']).checked;
         if (showPw != null && (showPw == true || showPw == "true")) {
             showPwType.type = "text";
         } else {
             showPwType.type = "password";
         }
    }
     
    function copyPasswordValue() {
         document.getElementById('newUser:passwordSecret').value = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value;
         alert('ENTRA PASSWORD PASTE');
    }
</script>

<f:view>
<br/><br/><br/>

    <% 
        if (session != null) {
            // Mejora para cerrar la sesion.
            session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            session.removeAttribute("authenticationBean");
        }
    %>

    <table class="fondoAreaTrabajoLogin" width="1114" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <!-- Tabla con header -->
        <tr height="123">
            <td class="fondoMenu1">&nbsp;</td>      
        </tr>
        <tr height="160">
            <td class="fondoMenu2">             
                <img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %><h:outputText value="#{authenticationBean.imagePeaje}" />" align="right">
            </td>       
        </tr>
        <tr height="320">
            <td class="fondoMenu3">
                            
                <h:form id="newUser">
                    <table class="tablaLogin">
                        <!-- Tr titulo -->
                        <tr height="24px">
                            <td class="titPantallaMenu" colspan="3">
                                <div class="divTitulo">
                                    <h:outputText id="titulo" value="#{userMessage.welcomeSaga}" />
                                    <h:inputHidden id="windowWidth" value="#{authenticationBean.widthScreen}"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Tr formulario -->
                        <tr>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="right" class="txt_formularios_login">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{userMessage.username}" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" class="colorCeldaTransparente">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <h:inputText id="userNameInput" size="20" maxlength="20"
                                    required="true" value="#{authenticationBean.loginName}"
                                    onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) putFocus(0,1);">
                                </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h:message for="userNameInput" styleClass="errorMessageLogin" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="right" class="txt_formularios_login">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{userMessage.pwdLogin}" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" class="colorCeldaTransparente">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <h:inputHidden id="passwordSecret" value="#{authenticationBean.password}" required="true"/> 
                                <input id="passwordInput" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h:message for="passwordSecret" styleClass="errorMessageLogin" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="right" class="txt_formularios_login">
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="showpw" onclick="showPassword()" />
                                    <h:outputText value="#{userMessage.showPwd}" />                                 
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="right" class="txt_formularios_login">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{userMessage.company}" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" class="colorCeldaTransparente">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{authenticationBean.idCompany}" converter="#{Long}"
                                    valueChangeListener="#{authenticationBean.changeCompany}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{authenticationBean.listOfCompany}"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="center"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="center"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="colorCeldaTransparente">
                                <div align="right">
                                    <h:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" onclick="copyPasswordValue()"
                                        styleClass="botones" action="#{authenticationBean.login }"
                                        value="#{userMessage.login_button_label}" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="errorMessage">
                            <td align="center" colspan="3">
                                <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="errorMessage" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </h:form>   
                    
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>

Del login.jsp la acción de este boton no ejecuta la función login:
<h:commandButton id="submit" type="submit" onclick="copyPasswordValue()"
styleClass="botones" action="#{authenticationBean.login }"
    value="#{userMessage.login_button_label}" />

Tambien os paso la clase AuthenticaionBean.java:
package com.project.web.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.project.base.server.ServiceLocator;
import com.project.base.util.LoggerMBean;
import com.project.constants.Companies;
import com.project.core.Company;
import com.project.core.params.CodesTable;
import com.project.service.CoreServicesConstants;
import com.project.user.Role;
import com.project.user.User;
import com.project.util.GeneralUtils;
import com.project.web.BaseBackBean;

/*******************************************************************************
 * 
 * La presente clase se utiliza para validar al usuario que ingresa a la aplicacion
 * 
 * @CCU 001
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "unchecked"})
public class AuthenticationBean extends BaseBackBean {
    
    
    private static final String FAIL = "failure";

    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    private static final String GOTOLOGOUT = "gotoLogout";
    
    private static final String MAXIM_FARE = "MAXIM_FARE";

    private String loginName;

    private String password;

    private Integer idCompany;

    private Company company;

    private User user;

    private Collection listOfCompany;

    boolean isFirstTime = false;

    boolean isLoged = false;
    
    private String imagePeaje;
    
    private String imageLogo;
    
    //Almacena los idiomas disponibles de la aplicación
    private HashMap<String, Locale> locales = null;
    
    private Locale myLocale;

    private String widthScreen;
    
    private ResourceBundle genericBundle = getBundle("bundle.site.Messages");
    
    //++ UNIFICADO
    private Integer selectedCompany;
    //-- UNIFICADO
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AuthenticationBean() {
        System.out.println("INICIALIZACIÓN AUTHENTICATIONBEAN");
        locales = new HashMap<String, Locale>(2);
        locales.put("spanish", new Locale("es", "ES"));
        locales.put("english", new Locale("en", "EN"));
             
        setMyLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        
        System.out.println("ANTES LOGOUT");
        logout();
        System.out.println("DESPUES LOGOUT");
 
        if (getSelectedCompany() == null) {
            Collection<SelectItem> companies = getListOfCompany();       
            if (!companies.isEmpty()) {
                Iterator<SelectItem> it = companies.iterator();
                setSelectedCompany((Integer) it.next().getValue());
            } 
        }
        
        this.setImagePeaje(GeneralUtils.getCodesTableValue("IMAGE_PEAJE", getSelectedCompany()));
        this.setImageLogo(GeneralUtils.getCodesTableValue("IMAGE_LOGO", getSelectedCompany()));
    }

    /**
     * Recupera el contexto de JSF
     * @return FacesContext
     */
    @Override
    public FacesContext getFacesContext() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Recupera ol objeto de la aplicacion
     * @return Application
     */
    @Override
    public javax.faces.application.Application getApplication() {
        return getFacesContext().getApplication();
    }

    /**
     * Recupera si el usuario actual esta logueado
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isLoged() {
        return isLoged;
    }

    /**
     * Setea si el usuario actual esta logueado
     * @param isLoged
     */
    public void setLoged(boolean isLoged) {
        this.isLoged = isLoged;
    }

    /**
     * Verifica que el usuario que se ha logeado sea un usuario validO
     * 
     * @return String
     * @MCU 001
     */
    public String login() {

        String resultLogin = FAIL;

        LoggerMBean appLogger = getLoger();
        appLogger.info("ENTRA LOGIN");
        appLogger.info(genericBundle.getString("start_login")+" " + loginName + ".");

        return "OK";
    }

    /**
     * Destruye la session inhabilitandola.
     * 
     * @return String
     * @MCU 001
     */
    public String logout() {

        LoggerMBean appLogger = getLoger();
        
        appLogger.info("Comenzando Proceso de Logout.");

        FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();

        // Quito el usuario de su session
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        
        if (session != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("authenticationBean");
            session.invalidate();
        }

        appLogger.info("Finalizando Proceso de Logout.");
        return GOTOLOGOUT;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna una lista de companias.
     * 
     * @return listOfCompany
     * @MCU 001
     */
    public Collection<SelectItem> getListOfCompany() {

        Collection<SelectItem> companiesToRender = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
         
        SelectItem si = new SelectItem();
        si.setDescription("company");
        si.setLabel("company");
        si.setValue(1); 
        companiesToRender.add(si);

        return companiesToRender;
    }

    /**
     * Recupera si es la primer vez que el usuario se loguea
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isFirstTime() {
        return isFirstTime;
    }

    /**
     * Setea si es la primer vez que el usuario se loguea
     * @param isFirstTime
     * @MCUnnn
     */
    public void setFirstTime(boolean isFirstTime) {
        this.isFirstTime = isFirstTime;
    }
    
    public String getImageLogo() {
        return imageLogo;
    }

    public void setImageLogo(String imageLogo) {
        this.imageLogo = imageLogo;
    }
    
    public String getImagePeaje() {
        return imagePeaje;
    }

    public void setImagePeaje(String imagePeaje) {
        this.imagePeaje = imagePeaje;
    }
    
    public Locale getMyLocale() {
        return myLocale;
    }

    public void setMyLocale(Locale myLocale) {
        this.myLocale = myLocale;
    }

    public String getWidthScreen() {
        return widthScreen;
    }

    public void setWidthScreen(String widthScreen) {
        this.widthScreen = widthScreen;
    }

    //++ UNIFICACION
    /**
     * Carga los parametros de la compañía seleccionada
     */
    public void changeCompany(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        Integer selectedComp = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
        this.setImagePeaje(GeneralUtils.getCodesTableValue("IMAGE_PEAJE", selectedComp));
        this.setImageLogo(GeneralUtils.getCodesTableValue("IMAGE_LOGO", selectedComp)); 
        setSelectedCompany(selectedComp);
    }

    public Integer getSelectedCompany() {
        return selectedCompany;
    }

    public void setSelectedCompany(Integer selectedCompany) {
        this.selectedCompany = selectedCompany;
    }
    //-- UNIFICACION
}

Donde en AuthenticationBean.java cuando el usuario haga click en el boton lo que esperaba es que ejecutase la función login, pero no lo hace:
public String login() {
        
    String resultLogin = FAIL;

    LoggerMBean appLogger = getLoger();
    appLogger.info("ENTRA LOGIN");
    appLogger.info(genericBundle.getString("start_login")+" " + loginName + ".");

    return "OK";
}

Y en el faces-config.xml tengo registrado la clase de la siguiente forma:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
                              "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd">
<faces-config>
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>authenticationBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.project.web.security.AuthenticationBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/pages/welcomeScreen.jsp</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<application>
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>es</default-locale>
   <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
  </locale-config>
  <message-bundle>bundle.site.Messages</message-bundle>
 </application>
</faces-config>

Si alguien tiene alguna idea o una solución, se lo agradecería. Cualquier ayuda es buena. Gracias de antemano.
Hay que tener en cuenta que es un proyecto antiguo con Java JDK 1.8, utilizo apache Tomcat v8.0 para el server y un compilador Ant. Con una versión Dynamic Web Module v2.4.

Prueba quitandole el type, y sacando el espacio dentro del action

Lo he probado pero sigue igual. Gracias.
